# How to set zindex with scrollview with image background

Tags: android, z-index

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/home_background"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             >
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
               >
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="50dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:text="text"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:text="text"
                        />
                </TableRow>
               ....
            </TableLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I have a scrollview with a bunch of table rows and a logo at the bottom. The logo overlaps the table. How can I get it to go underneath the scrollview? I have already tried with

```
view.bringToFront();
```

and

```
view.setTranslationZ(-10);
```

However, this hides the logo because the scrollview has an image background.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                >
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="50dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:text="text"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:text="text"
                        />
                </TableRow>
                ....
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```